# Typescript: how to refer to nested type on interface?

Tags: typescript

How do I refer to a type of a nested property of a typescript definition? This is what I tried:

```
// def.d.ts
declare module Def {
    type TFoo = {
        bar: (...args) => void;
    }
}

// script.ts
const bar: Def.TFoo.bar = function () {}; // Error TS2694: Namespace 'Def' has no exported member 'TFoo'
```

I know I can define it separately and refer to it:

```
// def.d.ts
declare module Def {
    type TFooBar = (...args) => void;
    type TFoo = {
        bar: TFooBar;
    }
}

// script.ts
const bar: Def.TFooBar = function (...args) {};
```

But I would like to use the definition in a more namespaced style, like the above example. How do I accomplish that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A type alias isn't a namespace, you cannot reference inner properties of it like that.
Just use another namespace/module:

```
declare module Def {
    module TFoo {
        type bar = (...args) => void;
    }
}
```